# Solving non-homogeneous recurrence relation with trigonometric functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

On the test at Discrete mathematics, we were given this non-homogeneous recurrence relation. $$a_{n}+5a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2} - 16a_{n-3} -48 a_{n-4} = \sin (\frac{\pi n}{3})+7^n.$$
So I was able to solve homogeneous part.
First I got roots from polynomial the
$
r^4 + 5r^3 + 6r^2 - 19r - 48,
$
which are ${2,-3,2-2i, 2+2i}$, and from here we can get the homogeneous part that is equal to:
$$
K_1\cdot 2^n + K_2\cdot (-3)^n + 2 \sqrt2 ^n(K_3\cdot \cos \frac{\pi n}{4} + K_4\cdot \sin \frac{\pi n}{4}).
$$

Then I solved the first part of non-homogeneous part: $A\cdot7^n$, but I have no clue on how to tackle $\sin(n)$.

Comment: Did you try to express sin(n) with complex exponential  ? It will give you geometric terms

Comment: @Lelouch But wouldn't that give me $i\cos (n) - ie^{in}$? I think that answer is $\sin (\frac {\pi n} {3}) + \cos (\frac {\pi n} {3})$

Comment: $$
\sin \theta=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta}-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \theta}}{2 i}
$$